# Laravel 9 Change Password with Current Password Using API

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I want to change a password in `Laravel 9` using `api`
I use `postman`, but I get a problem that I couldn't solve
I have tried more than one method and get the same error

this is route:

```
 Route::get('changePassword', [AuthController::class, 'ChangePassword']);
```

this is model :
[image]

and this is controller :

```
 public function ChangePassword(Request $request)
   {
      $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
         'old_password'        =>'required',
         'new_password'         =>'required|min:8|max:30',
         'confirm_password' =>'required|same:new_password'
      ]);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
         return response()->json([
            'message'=>'validations fails',
            'errors' =>$validator->errors()
         ],422);
      }
      $user=$request->user();

      if (Hash::check($request->old_password,$user->password)) {
         $user->update([
            'password'=>Hash::make($request->password)
         ]);


         return response()->json([
            'message'=>' password successfully updated',
            'errors' =>$validator->errors()
         ],200);
      }
      else
      {
         return response()->json([
            'message'=>'old password does not match',
            'errors' =>$validator->errors()
         ],422);
      }
   }
```

And the error I get in postman is :

[image]

What is the problem ?

Comment: looks like `$request->user()` might be returning null.

Comment: No I have set dd($user)
The result was to show the user whose token was entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it you are forgot new_password

```php
 public function ChangePassword(Request $request)
   {
      $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
         'old_password'        =>'required',
         'new_password'         =>'required|min:8|max:30',
         'confirm_password' =>'required|same:new_password'
      ]);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
         return response()->json([
            'message'=>'validations fails',
            'errors' =>$validator->errors()
         ],422);
      }
      $user=$request->user();

      if (Hash::check($request->old_password,$user->password)) {
         $user->update([
            'password'=>Hash::make($request->new_password)
         ]);


         return response()->json([
            'message'=>' password successfully updated',
            'errors' =>$validator->errors()
         ],200);
      }
      else
      {
         return response()->json([
            'message'=>'old password does not match',
            'errors' =>$validator->errors()
         ],422);
      }
   }
```